# How can use stream for a recusion in Java 8?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, java-8, stream

I have a method like this where I'm recursion with normal loop:

```
//    example for the args: "START" "RUN" "RUN" "END" "RUN" "START" "RUN" "END" "RUN"
//    expect: Listof.("START" "RUN" "RUN" "END", "START" "RUN" "END")
static List<String[]> findValidCommands(String[] args, List<String[]> listCommands) {

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i].matches("START")) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < args.length; j++) {
                    if ("END".equals(args[j])) {
                        listCommands.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, i, ++j));
                        return findValidCommands(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, j, args.length), listCommands);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return listCommands;
    }
```

I a beginners, please help me to improve my code with Stream.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you just trying to find pairs of START and END? I don't see why this should be recursive. Also, note that streams don't necessarily "improve" your code. If you think that every for loop should be rewritten in streams, you are too obsessed with streams :)

Comment: - "Are you just trying to find pairs of START and END?", that is all I want to do.
- "I don't see why this should be recursive", I don't know any other way, can u show me how, thank you.

Comment: Just replace the recursive call with a `break;` Would it give you any different results?

Comment: Ah I see. `i = j - 1;` and then `break;` should do the job. But really, this really isn't something that should be done in streams. I'd imagine the code to be way uglier than loops. I tried doing the version with just the `break;`, and it's already horrendous.

Comment: oh it give same result when I replace that. For more, Do u think it has another way for this case instead of using two For-loops and two If- condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code cannot be improved by Stream logic, quite the opposite.

It can however be improved by not using nested loops and not using recursion.

```java
static List<String[]> findValidCommands(String... args) {
    List<String[]> listCommands = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int start = -1, i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if (start == -1 && args[i].equals("START")) {
            start = i;
        } else if (start != -1 && args[i].equals("END")) {
            listCommands.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, start, i + 1));
            start = -1;
        }
    }
    return listCommands;
}
```

*Test*

```java
List<String[]> listCommands = findValidCommands(
        "START", "RUN", "RUN", "END", "RUN", "START", "RUN", "END", "RUN");
System.out.println(listCommands.stream().map(Arrays::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

*Output*

```
[START, RUN, RUN, END], [START, RUN, END]
```

Comment: oh thank you so much, you really saved me day